# Expressing and plotting functions: exploring relationships with x1, x2, and x3

Tags: plotting, functions

Let's consider three functions:

```
x1 = e^t + 2t^2 - 3;
x2 = t^3 - 2t + 5;
x3 = 2^t / (3t + 8)
```

How can we express or plot `x1` in terms of `x2 and x3` (3D plot with `x1, x2, x3` as axes), `x2` in terms of `x1 and x3`, and `x3` in terms of `x1 and x2`?

Usually, for simple functions, we can solve the equations to find `t` as a function of `x1, x2, or x3`, and then substitute it back into the functions to obtain the desired result. However, this approach can be difficult for complex functions.

If it is difficult to obtain explicit expressions or the resulting expressions are not straightforward, we can also focus on plotting the functions instead.
Also those functions above are just examples. The actual functions may be more complicated (real functions).

Comment: `ParametricPlot3D`

Comment: Change `e^...`to `E^...`or `Exp[...]`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
ParametricPlot3D[ {Exp[ t] + 2 t^2 - 3, t^3 - 2 t + 5,2^t/(3 t + 8)} , {t, 0, 10}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x1[t]", "x2[t]", "x3[t]"}]
```

[image]